# How can I get values of enum variable?

Tags: c#-4.0, enums

My question is how can I get values of enum variable?

[image]
Please look at the attached screenshot... "hatas" is a flag-enum. And I want to
get "HasError" - "NameOrDisplayNameTooShort" errors to show them.

```
using System;

namespace CampaignManager.Enums
{
    [Flags]
    public enum CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage
    {
        NoError = 0,
        HasError = 1,
        NameOrDisplaynameTooShort = 2,
        InvalidFirstName = 3,
    }
}
```

I tried simply;

```
Messagebox.Show(hatas);  // it's showing InvalidFirstName somehow...
```

Thank you very much for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: If you want to use the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) on your enum you need to define the values in powers of two like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage
{
    NoError = 0,
    HasError = 1,
    NameOrDisplaynameTooShort = 2,
    InvalidFirstName = 4,
}
```

To get parts of a flagged enum, try something like:

```
    var hatas = CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage.HasError | CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage.NameOrDisplaynameTooShort;
    var x = (int)hatas;

    for (int i=0; i<Enum.GetNames(typeof(CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage)).Length; i++)
    {
        int z = 1 << i; // create bit mask

        if ((x & z) == z) // test mask against flags enum
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage)z).ToString());
        }
    }
```

For getting the underlying value try casting:

```
Messagebox.Show(((int)hatas)ToString());
```

In your example, ToString is getting called by default against the CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage enum which return the string representation of the enum.

By casting to an int, the underlying default type for enums, you get ToString on the integer value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But MessageBox.Show((int)hatas);  is giving me compile time error as follows; Argument type 'int' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'.

Comment: Oops. Fixed. Try this: `Messagebox.Show(((int)hatas)ToString());`

Comment: Thanks again, but now it's getting "3". I want to get "HasError" - "NameOrDisplayNameTooShort". Somethinglike that; "Errors found; Application HasError and NameOrDisplayNameTooShort"....

Comment: OK, gotcha. Please see my edit for a new snippet. You can extract the concept into a method pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast/unbox the enum into an int as follows.

```
(int)CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage.NoError 
(int)CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage.HasError
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Messagebox.Show(CampaignCreaterUpdaterErrorMessage.NameOrDisplaynameTooShort);`

Comment: Nice try Charley14 :) But it's not the answer. Thanks for answering this anyway...